# AWS DynamoDB Updating A Map Element Inside A List

Tags: next.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table in DynamoDB:

```
{
    UserId: "123456",
    Orders: [
        {
            OrderId: "ORD123",
            OrderRef: "Christmas presents",
            OrderStatus: 0,
            OrderDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023",
            OrderItems: [
                {
                    ItemId: "ORD123-ITM001",
                    ItemDescription: "Socks",
                    ItemQuantity: 2,
                    ItemDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023",
                    ItemStatus: 0
                },
                {
                    ItemId: "ORD123-ITM002",
                    ItemDescription: "Tie",
                    ItemQuantity: 1,
                    ItemDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023",
                    ItemStatus
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            OrderId: "ORD456",
            OrderRef: "Birthday presents",
            OrderStatus: 0,
            OrderDeliveryDate: "23/12/2023",
            OrderItems: [
                {
                    ItemId: "ORD456-ITM001",
                    ItemDescription: "Cheese",
                    ItemQuantity: 1,
                    ItemDeliveryDate: "23/12/2023",
                    ItemStatus: 0
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to update the ItemStatus of ItemId: "ORD123-ITM001" from 0 to 2. I can do this by using the index numbers from the table in the following:

```
    const input = {
      TableName: tableName,
      Key: {
        UserId: user.userId,
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":sts": 2 },
      UpdateExpression: `SET Orders[0].OrderItems[0].ItemStatus= :sts`,
      ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
    };
    const command = new UpdateCommand(input);
    const response = await documentClient.send(command);
```

This works and updates the value but I would prefer to use the IDs to do the update, as opposed to using the indexes. The data in my app can change due to different sorting options so to ensure I get the correct index, I would have to scan the DB first then perform the update which I really don't want to do. Is there a way to write an expression to update the table using IDs instead of indexes?

The alternative I have tried is changing the Orders and OrderItems lists to maps (see below) and this works well with the IDs in dot notation. However, the issue I have with this is when my GetCommand returns data from the table, it doesn't work with .map in my NextJS app as Orders and OrderItems are no longer arrays. With this approach, is there a way to convert Orders and OrderItems to arrays?

```
{
  UserId: "123456",
  Orders: {
    ORD123: {
      OrderRef: "Christmas presents",
      OrderStatus: 0,
      OrderDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023",
      OrderItems: {
        ORD123_ITM001: {
          ItemDescription: "Socks",
          ItemQuantity: 2,
          ItemDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023",
          ItemStatus: 0,
        },
        ORD123_ITM002: {
          ItemDescription: "Tie",
          ItemQuantity: 1,
          ItemDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023",
          ItemStatus,
        },
      },
    },
    ORD456: {
      OrderRef: "Birthday presents",
      OrderStatus: 0,
      OrderDeliveryDate: "23/12/2023",
      OrderItems: {
        ORD456_ITM001: {
          ItemDescription: "Cheese",
          ItemQuantity: 1,
          ItemDeliveryDate: "23/12/2023",
          ItemStatus: 0,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Has anyone else come up against this and, if so, how did you overcome it? TIA

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, to update an item in a list you must first know the position of the list item. In most cases it's more favourable to use a map as you also correctly state.

Your issue is that you can no longer map the objects in your client side code, but you can just simply convert the map to an array using the following code:

Edit:

Opt1:

```
  Object.entries(map.Orders).map(order=> {
    console.log(order)
  })
```

Opt2:

```
for (const orderId in map.Orders) {
  const order = map.Orders[orderId];
  console.log(`Order ID: ${orderId}`);
  console.log(`Order Reference: ${order.OrderRef}`);
  console.log(`Order Delivery Date: ${order.OrderDeliveryDate}`);

  // Loop through order items
  for (const itemId in order.OrderItems) {
    const item = order.OrderItems[itemId];
    console.log(`  Item ID: ${itemId}`);
    console.log(`  Item Description: ${item.ItemDescription}`);
    console.log(`  Item Quantity: ${item.ItemQuantity}`);
    console.log(`  Item Delivery Date: ${item.ItemDeliveryDate}`);
    console.log(`  Item Status: ${item.ItemStatus}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Leeroy! In your code snippet above, I have swapped myMap for the map from my original post but the return value is an empty array [ ]. Do I also need to change .map(([key, val]) => ({key, val})); to something that is specific to my map? Thanks

Comment: I'm not online right now to test, but try my second solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider breaking the data up into separate entries in your table. One entry for each order and one for each item in an order. You can use a query to get an order and all its items. To accomplish this you need to have a partition key and sort key pattern that allows you to store different objects in the same table. You'll often here this referred to as a single table pattern.

The table typically has partition and sort keys with generic names (`PK` and `SK`). The data would then look something like this (each object is a separate entry in the table):

```
{
    PK: "123456",
    SK: "ORDER#ORD123",
    UserId: "123456",
    OrderId: "ORD123",
    OrderRef: "Christmas presents",
    OrderStatus: 0,
    OrderDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023"
}
{
    PK: "123456",
    SK: "ORDER#ORD123#ITEM#ORD123-ITM001",
    ItemId: "ORD123-ITM001",
    ItemDescription: "Socks",
    ItemQuantity: 2,
    ItemDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023",
    ItemStatus: 0
}
{
    PK: "123456",
    SK: "ORDER#ORD123#ITEM#ORD123-ITM001",
    ItemId: "ORD123-ITM002",
    ItemDescription: "Tie",
    ItemQuantity: 1,
    ItemDeliveryDate: "21/12/2023",
    ItemStatus
}
{
    PK: "123456",
    SK: "ORDER#ORD456",
    UserId: "123456",
    OrderId: "ORD456",
    OrderRef: "Birthday presents",
    OrderStatus: 0,
    OrderDeliveryDate: "23/12/2023"
}
{
    PK: "123456",
    SK: "ORDER#ORD456#ITEM#ORD456-ITM001",
    ItemId: "ORD456-ITM001",
    ItemDescription: "Cheese",
    ItemQuantity: 1,
    ItemDeliveryDate: "23/12/2023",
    ItemStatus: 0
}
```

You'll notice that each record has the same `PK` (the user ID) and the `SK` starts with `ORDER#<OrderId>`. The item records also inclue `#ITEM#<ItemId>`. This allows you to retrieve the order without the items by doing a *get* operation (PK = UserId and SK = `ORDER#<OrderId>`) or you can use a *query* to retrieve the order WITH the items (PK = UserId and begins_with(SK, `ORDER#<OrderId>`). The query will return the order as well as each item. You can then put that together to form the object you have above.

By taking this approach you can update a single item on an order very easily because each order item is its own entry in the table.

You may find that you need to access the data in different ways, which is where GSIs come in. For the limited example you've given this should work, or be close to what you need.